# Dictionaries, nested values to slice and dice menus

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

How can I create a function that will enable to calculate calories of a combination of both meals and individual dishes?

I have two dictionaries

```
meals = {"Happy Meal": ["Cheese Burger", "French Fries", "Coca Cola"], "Best Of Big Mac": ["Big Mac", "French Fries", "Coca Cola"], "Best Of McChicken": ["McChicken", "Salad", "Sprite"]}

poor_calories = {"Hamburger": 250, "Cheese Burger": 300, "Big Mac": 540, "McChicken": 350, "French Fries": 230, "Salad": 15, "Coca Cola": 150, "Sprite": 150}
```

*This is what I have so far:* (I'm failing in building a connection of the two dictionaries and creating a function with a loop that works.)

```
print(meals.get("Happy Meal"))
print(meals.get("Best Of Big Mac"))
print(meals.get("Best Of McChicken"))


def advanced_calories_counter(meals, key):
    return meals.get(key, "item_name not found")

print(advanced_calories_counter(meals,'Happy Meal'))

menu = {**meals, **poor_calories}
print(menu)

for key in menu:
  print(key)

def menu4(key):
  for calories, dish in poor_calories.items():
    for meal, dish in meals.items():
      print(calories, dish, meal, meals[key][value])

print(menu4("Happy Meal"))
```

Comment: How do you want the function to work?

Comment: e.g. if I call Happy Meal, I want following Output: Cheeseburger 300, French Fries 230, Coca Cola 150. I fail to get the connection

Comment: `def menu(menu_name): {food: poor_calories.get(food, food + ' not found') for food in menu_name}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a comprehension:

```
out = {meal: {dish: poor_calories[dish] for dish in dishes}
         for meal, dishes in meals.items()}
print(out)

#Output:
{'Happy Meal': {'Cheese Burger': 300, 'French Fries': 230, 'Coca Cola': 150},
 'Best Of Big Mac': {'Big Mac': 540, 'French Fries': 230, 'Coca Cola': 150},
 'Best Of McChicken': {'McChicken': 350, 'Salad': 15, 'Sprite': 150}}
```

If you want the total calories per menu:

```
out2 = {meal: sum(poor_calories[dish] for dish in dishes) 
          for meal, dishes in meals.items()}
print(out2)

# Output
{'Happy Meal': 680, 'Best Of Big Mac': 920, 'Best Of McChicken': 515}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought it way too complicated

Answer (score 0):

Using `operator.itemgetter` and a comprehension:

```
from operator import itemgetter

{meal: dict(zip(items, itemgetter(*items)(poor_calories))) for meal, items in meals.items()}
```

---

```
{'Best Of Big Mac': {'Big Mac': 540, 'Coca Cola': 150, 'French Fries': 230},
 'Best Of McChicken': {'McChicken': 350, 'Salad': 15, 'Sprite': 150},
 'Happy Meal': {'Cheese Burger': 300, 'Coca Cola': 150, 'French Fries': 230}}
```

And to get the meal calories:

```
{meal: sum(itemgetter(*items)(poor_calories)) for meal, items in meals.items()}
```

---

```
{'Best Of Big Mac': 920, 'Best Of McChicken': 515, 'Happy Meal': 680}
```